# In-app purchase query inventory exception

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement in-app purchases using the example from developer.android.com and of course since it's Google, it doesn't work. As in their example, in the `onCreate()` method of my app I have:

```
mHelper = new IabHelper(this, publicKey);
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
            Log.d("iap","Iab error: "+result.getMessage());
            return;
        } 
        Log.d("iap","In-app Billing set up successfully");
    }
});
```

And I have a method to query/refresh inventory of in-app purchases like:

```
public void refreshIAP() {
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, skuList, mQueryFinishedListener);
}
```

The problem is the `queryInventoryAsync()` method crashes the application with the error `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`.
It works fine if I call this method from the `onIabSetupFinished()` but I don't want to do that - I want to be able to call this method whenever I want (after the setup is finished of course).
I don't know what is this `Looper.prepare()` thing, and because it's not referenced anywhere in the Android docs example, I assume it's not required and I just misunderstood something.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51420796/6533853

Answer (score 2):

You should call refreshIAP on UI thread like this

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        refreshIAP();       
    }
});
```